# A/C Reciever Drier for 1962 Skylark

Tags: ac, buick, skylark

I need to replace the A/C receiver drier (a.k.a. accumulator) in my 1962 Buick Skylark (V8 convertible), however the aftermarket ones I've been finding online (e.g. http://www.partsgeek.com/gbproducts/DC/13745-05039271.html) have different inlets than the current one in my car (see pictures below).  Does anyone know where I can find one that looks like this? Or, is there an adapter available that could make the others compatible?

Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Comment: That is all I'm seeing as well ... are you sure what you have in there isn't an aftermarket A/C system or one which was dealer installed? If so, it might be different than what would have came from the factory. I'm not sure how you could tell exactly. It looks as though both ends of your drier have nipples (or male ends). The ones I'm seeing have only female connections, and then in the wrong locations (both on top). I've looked at several different places with the same results.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response.  As far as I know (and I'm pretty much positive), this A/C system isn't aftermarket.  In fact, the same receiver drier in the car now is also shown in the original shop manual. After more searching, I was able to find this: [link] (http://www.ebay.com/itm/HD-ACCUMULATOR-DRIER-KENWORTH-PETE-W-KYSOR-1960-1976/171157649196?_trksid=p2045573.c100033.m2042&_trkparms=aid%3D111001%26algo%3DREC.SEED%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20131017132637%26meid%3D7947938283091778358%26pid%3D100033%26prg%3D20131017132637%26rk%3D1%26rkt%3D4%26sd%3D171157649196) which looks similar...

Comment: Not sure about compatibility though, since it's not specific to a 62 skylark. Any thoughts?

Comment: I have looked on many different restoration parts web sites to no avail (I'm sure you did the same). I'm sure the driers I found are the same ones as you. The one you show I would bet Will NOT work, mainly due to fitment. I think your best bet is to contact [these guys](http://www.classicautoair.com/restoration-services.html) to see about building a new one. If "original" is given up for "functional", you could probably do this with any drier of the same size, but you'd have to build lines and fittings to connect it.

Comment: as to the adapter part I'd assume it's NPT threads. If you goto a parts store and they have the part in stock you could ask them to find an adapter for it.